# Can't connect to Wi-Fi no matter how hard I try

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, router, drivers

**System:** Lenovo Ideapad S500 Touch
**OS:** Windows 10 Home (64 bit)
**Card:** Qualcomm Atheros AR9485WB-EG Wireless Network Adapter

So a few days ago my Wi-Fi randomly stopped working and started giving me the "Can't connect to network." error. 29 total hours of research later and I've learned a lot, but I'm still no closer to fixing my problem. (For context, all other devices in the house can connect to the network fine, so it has to be something wrong with *my* pc)

When I say I've tried everything, I literally have tried *everything.*

-I've uninstalled and reinstalled my network driver, I updated it to the latest version I could find online (2017), I also must have went in Properties almost a hundred times by now (changing the DNS to Cloudfare or Google, I went to the "Power Managment" tab and disabled "Allow the computer to turn this device off to save power" etc etc...

-I've installed multiple Driver Updater programs.

-Ran all the troubleshooters on Windows 10 and even an older one I downloaded from another computer and used a USB stick to transfer it.

-Tried every CMD command under the sun (things like netsh int ip reset reset.log, ipconfig /flushdns, etc), upon which I'll usually get the "Access Denied" or "Media disconnected" error.

-Tinkered with countless services in "services.msc" and messed with all kinds of permissions in "regedit" to allow me to execute the commands, which appeared to work at the time but does nothing after a restart.

-Tried disabling and reenabling Ipv6, also tried adding the network manually.

If you can find any kind of solution online, chances are I've tried it.

**I have however learned 4 interesting things through pure trial and error.**

1. I can connect to my router using an Ethernet cable, and it works perfectly (it's how I'm able to write this post right now).
2. While on another computer to connect to an online class I discovered the "Mobile Hotspot" feature which, surprisingly enough, allows me to connect to the network. So I can connect to the network through another PC's mobile hotspot but not directly.
3. In Device Manager, if I turn on "Show hidden devices", 4 new network adapters appear. (See Image 1)
   2 are greyed out. They have generic names so I can't find drivers for them online (they seem to be outdated though, 2006).
4. When I *can* connect through Ethernet or a pc's hotspot, while on Chrome I'm not able to access a multitude of sites and I get a DNS related error (See Image 2).

Thank you for reading my long post. If *anyone* out there can help me with this problem I'd be eternally grateful. This issue and the endless attempts to fix this problem to no avail are making me go **insane.**    [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7avsG.jpg)  [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnQWr.jpg)

Comment: Get and try a USB Wireless Adapter and try that. It appears you have an incompatibility between the Atheros card and your network. A different USB adapter will help you determine this.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a software problem? I've been able to connect to the network for months before this. How could it just *stop* being compatible all of a sudden?

Comment: I'd recommend building a bootable Linux USB drive (such as Ubuntu or Linux Mint), boot to the flash drive, and see if another OS can connect to wireless. If you can connect, then you'll know it's Windows/driver and not a hardware issue. If you still can't connect, then technically you don't know whether it's hardware or software but it will give you a slightly better idea.

Comment: Did you try rebooting your AP (wireless router)? APs have to track the state of each wireless client device that joins the network, so if your AP got stuck with bad state information for that one client, it might be too confused to let that one client on, even as it continues to service other clients just fine. Don't assume "everything else is working fine on this AP" means "it can't be the AP's fault"; it could definitely still be the AP's fault.

Answer (score 0):

Testing with a separate adapter is always a good troubleshooting step.

You have tried the network software solutions and that did not work.

Hardware can fail / go intermittent at any point.

If you think it is a software problem, execute the initial Windows 10 Repair Steps.

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run in order:

dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /StartComponentCleanup

dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth

SFC  /SCANNOW

Then restart and test.

If DISM/SFC fail and you still think Software, run a Windows 10 Repair Install.

Go to the Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.